# Alternative Strategy for using plaintext credentials in Java code

Tags: java

I want to send a POST request to an endpoint, which involves sending the following in the Body:

`{"userid" : "someusername" , "password" : "somepassword"}`

I'm currently writing this body, including the password inside my code. My requirement is that I cannot write the password in the code. Not sure of the userid, but it may not be allowed in the future as well.

What strategy should I use such that I don't write the username and password in my code, but still I'm able to access and connect to the endpoint.

Comment: A) way too broad - whole books are written about such aspects of security B) and very much depends on context. The user name for example could/should be something that well, the user provides when logging into *your* application.

Comment: I'm asking if there are any strategies which we can use which does not involve specifying the username and password in the code? I'm open to storing them in a separate file and read from them, but will that be a secure way?

Comment: As I told you: there are gazillions of different ways of solving this. This community isn't about recommending *strategies*, it is about answering specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

Jasypt can be used to encrypt and decrypt passwords you've stored in your configuration files.

The library includes support for transparently accessing variables in spring, and hibernate.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

- read from file
- pass username / password as arguments to the program
- query the user at the start of the program for username/password

This depends on your exact requirements also, if the issue is only that no credentials should be in code, but during runtime it doesn't really need to be secure, then any of the above is ok.